# How to disable the flash prompt for camera and microphone access?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

how do i disable the flash prompt that comes for microphone and camera access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, this is a security issue.

I believe people can allow access to microphone and camera without a prompt, but they have to tick the right boxes in their Flash preferences

Comment: is there any work around? because my actual recording takes place through java..In my action script i just want to detect the mic activity level.

Comment: Sorry mate, no workaround for this. Although if you are on one page with an applet and a Flash object, you can use intrapage communication to send values from Java to Flash using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, I think you can't, especially for security reasons. If you could do it, that would mean someone could record you without you know anything about it.

Comment: is there any work around? because my actual recording takes place through java..In my action script i just want to detect the mic activity level.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around. However, you have to set it manually.
Go to https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html.
and add your website to always allow.And, restart the browser. That can be used for testing purpose. 
 [image]